# Fourier Transform of shifted unit step function

Tags: fourier-transform

Find the Fourier transform of 
$$x(t) = (t-2) e^{-t} u(t-2)$$
I got $e^{-t}u(t-2) \to (e^{-2j2\pi f})/j2\pi f$ but i'm not sure how to combine with the term $(t-2)$. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try integration by parts.

Comment: $Y(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y(t) e^{-2i \pi ft}dt, Y'(f) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty  y(t)(-2i \pi  t) e^{-2i \pi ft}dt$ (if it converges..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that $$\mathcal{F}\{te^{-t}u(t)\}=\frac{1}{(1+j\omega)^2}$$

Then we can see that

$$\begin{align}x(t) &= (t-2) e^{-t} u(t-2)\\
&=\frac{e^{2}}{e^{2}}\left( (t-2) e^{-t} u(t-2)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{e^{2}}\left((t-2) e^{-(t-2)} u(t-2)\right)\end{align}$$

From$$\mathcal{F}\{f(t-t_0)\}=F(j\omega)e^{-j\omega t_0}$$ (for $t_0=2$) and the linearity of the FT we can conclude that

$$\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}=\frac{1}{e^{2}}\frac{1}{(1+j\omega)^2}e^{-2j\omega}=\frac{e^{-2(1+j\omega)}}{(1+j\omega)^2}$$